# Swift: Expected expression error in api call

Tags: swift

This my first post - new to Swift. Building my first real app on Yelp api.

I am getting an expected expression error in my searchWithCLL methods. I think it might be because of cll(latitude, longitude). Or maybe my variables?  Can anyone advise?

```
func getYelpBusinesses() {

    // Current Location
    var currentLocation = locationManager.location
    var latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
    var longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude


    client.searchWithCLL(term: "Returants", location:"Toronto", cll: (latitude, longitude), success: { (request:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, object:AnyObject!); -> Void in self.yelpHandler.saveYelpObjects(object)}) { (request:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        //Present an alert view
}
}
```

Thank you for feedback.

Comment: You have an extra semicolon after `(request:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, object:AnyObject!)`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aderstedt already mentioned in the comments, there is a typo in your Code You don't need that semicolon there:

```
(request:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, object:AnyObject!);
                                                    ^
```

Remove it, and it should work as expected.